# Unable to Inspect an Element using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-devtools

I have a base html file (base.html) and inside of it resides an iframe that uses (iframe.html). The iframe only shows up when a certain menu item is clicked. 
They are both hosted on the same domain.

In base.html I'm including a script that points to an external service that I use. Including the script returns an object that lives on my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalSite.com/myID.js"></script>
```

In iframe.html I have another script that builds a menu based on some of the attributes of the object that is returned

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_list_builder.js"></script>
```

the code for my_list_builder.js looks something like this:

```
var myList = parent.externalAPI.getItems()
var listBlock = "<div><ul>"

for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    listBlock += '<li><span>'+ myList[i].Name + '</span></li>';
}

listBlock += '</ul></div>'

$('someElement').append(listBlock);
```

Now, this code executes as expected and adds the listBlock to the page where I want it, but when I try to inspect any of the elements within the iframe in Chrome I am unable to do so. The iframe is the lowest level element I can inspect, but it doesn't have the usual dropdown option. If I remove the my_list_builder.js I'm able to inspect the elements in the iframe without any trouble.

Any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: This happens regularly on jsfiddle.net. If you hit shift-enter or the "run" toolbar button to update the preview window, the inspector won't  work in the preview window until you hit "save"/"update". Something to do with dynamically generated content in an iframe, for sure. Would love to know why, or if there's a chromium issue to star.

Comment: I've found a weird sort of work around for the time being, though I'm no closer to the 'why' of why it has issues in the first place. This workaround is also not consistent, but I figured I'd list it incase others have had similar issues. If I place break points in my_list_builder.js and step through them, then after the iframe has finished loading, I'm able to inspect the elements in the iframe. If I remove the breakpoints, make any changes to my_list_builder.js and save then reload, then the problem crops back up. Not sure why the breakpoints have helped, but I'm glad they do!

Comment: I think you should log this as a bug @ the chrome bug tracker, not as a question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `debugger` keyword inside your iframe/non-iframe scripts. Simply putting `debugger;` on a line, should programmatically cause a breakpoint in the Chrome Developer Tools (also Firebug). More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger